# Разность двойных слов в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Хочу реализовать, казалось бы, элементарную задачу - нахождение разности двойных слов на 16-битном процессоре, используя TASM. Но не всё так просто, как оказалось. Мой алгоритм таков:

1. Находим модуль разности младших частей двойных слов и записываем какой у нас был знак внутри модуля.
2. Находим разность старших частей двойных слов.
3. Два варианта:

   1. Если разность меньше нуля, то берем модуль от разности старших частей, записываем в старшую часть результата, модуль разности младших частей записываем в младшую часть результата. Затем меняем знак результата.
   2. Если разность больше нуля. Если знак в модуле в шаге (1) был отрицательный, то делаем декремент старшей части, в младшую часть результата записываем FFFF - мл. ч. вычитаемого + мл. ч. уменьшаемого. Записываем в результат.

Возможно, я всё усложняю. Буду рад услышать более оптимальный путь решения задачи. Текущая моя проблема - то, что я не могу нормально поменять знак двойного слова в шаге 3.1.

Мой код довольно объемный, поэтому я не стал вставлять его в вопрос, а доступен он по этой ссылке: https://pastebin.com/5vFXvhes